# C# define array like PHP

Tags: c#, arrays

I have PHP array code like this:

```
$waypoint = [
    10 => [
        [80, 432],
        [320, 432],
        [1160, 432],
    ],
    20 => [
        [80, 432],
        [320, 432],
        [1160, 432],
    ],
];
```

How can I do in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want a `Dicitionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
var keyValues = new Dictionary<int, int[,]>
{
    { 10, new int[,]{ { 80, 432 }, { 320, 432 }, { 1160, 432 } } },
    { 20, new int[,]{ { 80, 432 }, { 320, 432 }, { 1160, 432 } } },
    { 30, new int[,]{ { 80, 432 }, { 320, 432 }, { 1160, 432 } } }
};
```

[Read more about `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8)